# Import pictures into ubuntu Shotwell from Windows XP

Tags: nautilus

How can I transfer pictures in Windows XP into Ubuntu Shotwell?
I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows XP partitioned equally on a 500GB hard disc.Here's what I tried:I select File in Shotwell,then Import from Folder. The folder containing the pictures in XP is 108CANON. I create that folder in Shotwell and it appears  i n the list.(it also appears in Files & Folders in the Dash). I click on the 108CANON, then OK. Next, Import to Library page appears. I click Copy Photos. Now a page presenting ambiguous info appears: Importing, a blue progress bar scanning back and forth across the bottom of a black screen, and a box titled Import Complete telling me Import complete, No photos...imported.
To my mind, these functions all seem intuitive, but lead me nowhere.

I understand what "mount" means in computer terminology, but I don't know how to make Ubuntu "see" the Windows partition - and the folder within it. I sense this is the key to doing a successful import.

Comment: Is this a dual boot, or are these septate computers, what is the format of the pictures?

Comment: Please do not put your answer inside the question. You can answer your own question below where it says "Your Answer." Later you can accept your own answer as the correct one. Accepting the correct answer will help others who may have the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that Ubuntu can see the Windows partition and make sure it's mounted (you can also do it through Shotwell).

I assume Windows and Ubuntu are on the same PC?

- With Shotwell open, go to "File" (my desktop language isn't English, but the words should match quite closely) in the top bar and choose "Import from map".
- Go to the map on your Windows partition, find the folder(s) you want to import and press "OK" once they are selected.
- It should now prompt you to ask if you want to copy the pictures to Ubuntu or not: choose whatever option you like. Now they should be imported and/or copied.

If you chose not to copy the pictures, you will need to make sure the Windows partition is mounted every time you want to use Shotwell.

Edit: In case I misunderstood, the other way around isn't possible (while you are logged in on Windows), as far as I know, since Windows doesn't recognize GNU/Linux (and other non-Windows?) partitions.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure that worked for me.

To mount (access) the Windows partition in Ubuntu, one must know that Ubuntu recognizes the partition by size not by name; therefore, the logical size item in the PLACES menu is 288GB volume. Secondly, one must know the name of the Windows file(s) one wishes to access. So, the sequence of events for me is: With Ubuntu open, Home, 288GB volume, Documents and Settings, John, My Documents, My pictures ... and for music files, substitute My Music for My Pictures. Simple enough when one knows how. Hope this will be helpful to other Ubuntu novices.